# Solve $y'' + 2y' + y = \begin{cases} 4e^t, & 0 \leq t < 1 \\ 0, &t \geq 1 \end{cases}$ where $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform

Hi can you help me solve this?  I have no idea how to solve the initial problem by Laplace transform when it is a piecewise function.

Solve the initial value problem using Laplace transform on $$y'' + 2y' + y = \begin{cases} 4e^t, & 0 \leq t < 1 \\ 0, &t \geq 1 \end{cases}$$ where $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(\mathcal Lf)(s) = {} & \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 4e^t e^{-st} \, dt \\[8pt]
& \text{and so on.}
\end{align}